# When importing Numpy from Flask in Virtualenv Numpy gives multiarray import error

Tags: python, numpy, flask, import, virtualenv

I'am trying to import numpy at flask `__init__.py` but it gives this error :

```
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all 
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

When I remove the import from flasks `__init__.py` everything works.
When I do `from numpy.core import multiarray` in virtualenv everything works but importing it from wsgi is not working.

here is the apache/site-available config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 192.168.0.1
                ServerAdmin hello@world.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
                <Directory /home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/home/bar/FlaskApp:/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
```

and here is wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/bar/FlaskApp")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'FlaskApp'
```

Thanks

Additional Info:
I have no problems importing other modules like pandas, flask or os.
Originally i import pandas so error comes as a pandas dependency error.
from `/var/log/apache/error.log`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
        from FlaskApp import app as application
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from myscript import myclass
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line$
        "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
        ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Here is the error log when i tried to import numpy directly from `__init__.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
        from FlaskApp import app as application
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        import numpy as np
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
    File "/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError:
    Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
    likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
    If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
    files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

It works without a problem when i try to import numpy in venv in a python session.

```
(venv) bar@bar:~/FlaskApp/FlaskApp$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.core import multiarray
>>> multiarray.__file__
'/home/bar/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imports under mod_wsgi can be tricky, particularly with Python C extension libraries.

The issue here turned out to be setting the [`WSGIDaemonProcess`](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) `python-path=` option to a venv with the compiled module. From those docs:

> If using a Python virtual environment, rather than use this option to refer to the site-packages directory of the Python virtual environment, you should use the python-home option to specify the root of the Python virtual environment instead.
>
> In all cases, if the directory contains Python packages which have C extension components, those packages must have been installed using the same base Python version as was used to compile the mod_wsgi module. You should not mix packages from different Python versions or installations.

So, the `python-home=` option must be used for the venv dir given, *and* either Python 2.7 should be used for the venv, or the Python 3 build of mod_wsgi must be installed (`libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` on Ubuntu).

For some applications, the [`WSGIApplicationGroup`](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html) needs to be configured as follows too:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

In the case that any of the C extensions use the simplified threading api.

From similar questions, [α](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html), [β](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405125/issue-with-imports-when-using-wsgi-in-ec2-instance-to-host-flask-app/43303368), this seems to be a common issue.

Comment: Still same error but I understand the problem better. Thanks

Comment: So I need pyton2.7 modules in my virtualenv. I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: I created virtualenv with python 2.7 and installed the modules and change the config file's path to it.  Everthing works. Thanks a lot. I will import some print functions now.

Comment: Great, glad it works, I'll edit my answer to be a bit clearer given that. :)

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work using python3? I'm having the same issue, but don't want to revert to python2.7. I have libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed, but still get the same error.

Comment: @Brandon Are you sure your venv is using the same Python 3 version as the apache extension was compiled with? For instance, on xenial the distro package uses 3.5 but you may well have a 3.6 virtual env.