# What's the source of thread-unsafety in this usage of pandas.Series.reindex(, copy=True)?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

Calling `pd.Series.reindex` is not thread safe ([bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25870)).
My question is *why* is Series.reindex (which returns a copy and seems like a functionally pure operation) not thread safe, even when no-one is writing to that object's data?

The operation I'm performing is:

```
s = pd.Series(...)
f(s)  # Success!

# Thread 1:
   while True: f(s)  

# Thread 2:
   while True: f(s)  # Exception !
```

... which fails for `f(s): s.reindex(..., copy=True)`.

So, why did the threaded call fail? I'm surprised at this, because if there were any thread-not-safe calls, such as populating the Series' index, I would have thought these would done their mutating work already in the main thread.

Pandas *does* have [an open issue that `.copy` is not threadsafe](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2728). However, the discussion there is around issues of people reading and writing to the object at the same time.

The maintainers [marked the `.reindex` not-thread-safe issue as a duplicate of the `.copy` issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25870#issuecomment-476373637). I'm suspicious that it has the same cause, but if `.copy` is the source, then I suspect *almost all of pandas is not thread safe in any situation*, ever for 'functionally pure' operations.

```
import traceback
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def f(arg):
    s,idx = arg
    try:
        # s.loc[idx].values   # No problem
        s.reindex(idx) # Fails
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
    return None


def gen_args(n=10000):
    a = np.arange(0, 3000000)
    for i in xrange(n):
        if i%1000 == 0:
            # print "?",i
            s = pd.Series(data=a, index=a)
            f((s,a)) # <<< LOOK. IT WORKS HERE!!!
        yield s, np.arange(0,1000)

# for arg in gen_args():
#     f(arg)   # Works fine

t = ThreadPool(4)
for result in t.imap(f, gen_args(), chunksize=1):
    # print "==>", result
    pass
```