# pandas multithreading inconsistencies on indexes of copied dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I have `n` thread workers doing operations on the same `dataframe`. Because pandas is not thread safe (even for read only, [python pandas dataframe thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592618/python-pandas-dataframe-thread-safe)), I do `n` copies of the dataframe **BEFORE** running the threads (and not during the thread to avoid locking mechanismes https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/gotchas/gotchas8.html). And still I have this weird behavior that I do not have in sequential execution:

```
df = # some dataframe with unique index
assert df.index.is_unique # it passes
dfs = [df.copy() for _ in range(0,n)]

def target(d):
    
    if not d.index.is_unique:
        # if should not pass here, but it does
        assert d.index.duplicated().sum() != 0 # it does not pass!

for _ in range(0,n):
    threading.Thread(target=target, args=(dfs[_],)).start()
```

The index is unique, but in some threads, it is seen as not unique, but the sum of non-unique indexes is zero.

I would suspect it comes from this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

> While Index objects are copied when deep=True, the underlying numpy
> array is not copied for performance reasons. Since Index is immutable,
> the underlying data can be safely shared and a copy is not needed.

Note that some runs work. So it is definitely a race condition problem.